# Probability and Combinations to place 3 indistinguishable balls in 3 distinguishable urns using stars and stripes.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Say have 3 indistinguishable balls (K=3) to be placed in 3 distinguishable  urns (U=3). By using stars and stripes the number of combinations is C(K+U-1,K) = C(5,3) = 10. The 10 cases are listed below. The 3 stars are the placement of the  K =3 indistinguishable balls and the 2 vertical lines separate the 3 urns called U1,U2,U3 in order.

Balls in urns U1|U2|U3 . B is a ball

B|B|B   ie 1 ball each urn
BBB||    ie 3 balls urn 1
|BBB|    Ie 3 balls urn 2
||BBB
BB|B|  2 balls urn 1 and 1 ball urn 2
BB||B 
B|BB|
|BB|B
B||BB
|B||BB 1 ball urn 1 and 2 balls urn 3

Is the probability for each of these 10 cases the same- ie 1/10 ? If not how do you determine each case probability. People always calculate the total number of combinations but never discuss the probability of each case. Sorry about lousy formatting.

Comment: The probability depends on how the balls are placed in the urns. The answer below assumes that each ball has an equal chance of being placed in each bin. But the balls might be placed in a different  way. For example if the balls were fermions and the urns energy levels, there might be a maximum of 2 balls per urn.

Comment: To determine the probability of each case, count the number of arrangements $n$ of distinguishable balls which correspond to that case, then $n/27$ is the probability of that case.

Comment: Suppose you had every possible outcome listed. You randomly select the outcome you want from a uniform distribution of outcomes, then you add the balls to the urns to match that outcome. Now, every outcome has an equal probability of occurring. So, it is definitely dependent on how you decide to add the balls to the urns which determines the probabilities of the outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

The cases are not equally likely.  This can be seen by first distributing distinct balls to distinct bins, then painting all the balls the same color to make them indistinguishable.

Say we have a blue ball, a green ball, and a red ball.  There are three ways to distribute each ball, giving $3^3 = 27$ possible distributions, each of which is equally likely to occur if the balls are distributed randomly.  Notice that there is only one way to put all the balls in the first bin.  However, there are $3! = 6$ ways to place one ball in each bin.  Therefore, we are six times as likely to find one ball in each bin than to find all the balls in the first bin.

Finally, paint all the balls white to make them indistinguishable.  The physical situation has not changed, just our perception of whether the balls are distinguishable.